# Using eConnect to create an RMA with line/serial items

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, econnect

I am in the process of creating a custom interface to receive items on an RMA and am using eConnect to do this. I am encountering an error that specifies the Return_Record_Type is missing. In the XML document it is clearly there. I am attaching the error and xml document along with the code that is setting it. I am using C# to perform this.

C# Code:

```
//RMA Serial Item ( GP Table: SVC05255)

detailcount = 0;

taFSRMALineSerial_ItemsTaFSRMALineSerial serialitem = new taFSRMALineSerial_ItemsTaFSRMALineSerial();

serialitem.Return_Record_Type = 1;

serialitem.RETDOCID = rmaheader.RETDOCID;

 serialitem.CUSTNMBR = rmaheader.CUSTNMBR;

serialitem.LNSEQNBR = 100;

serialitem.QTYTYPE = 1;

 serialitem.ITEMNMBR = "VX510 DC";

serialitem.SERLNMBR = "2-2-2-2";

serialitem.SERLTQTY = 1;

serialitem.SLTSQNUM = detailcount + 1;

 serialitem.ADRSCODE = "PRIMARY";

 serialitem.LOCNCODE = "RETURN";

serialitem.SVC_Original_Serial = 1;

 serialitem.SVC_Original_SerialSpecified = true;

serialitem.UpdateIfExists = 1;

serialitems[detailcount] = serialitem;
```

eConnect Error:

Procedure or function 'taFSRMALineSerial' expects parameter '@I_vReturn_Record_Type', which was not supplied.

```
XMLDocument:

<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
- <eConnect xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
- <FSRMAType>
  <eConnectProcessInfo xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <taRequesterTrxDisabler_Items xsi:nil="true" /> 
- <taFSRMALineSerial_Items>
- <taFSRMALineSerial>
  <Return_Record_Type>1</Return_Record_Type> 
  <RETDOCID>RMA0KFP000002</RETDOCID> 
  <CUSTNMBR>BBTFINANC027494</CUSTNMBR>
  <ADRSCODE>PRIMARY</ADRSCODE> 
  <LNSEQNBR>100</LNSEQNBR> 
  <ITEMNMBR>VX510 DC</ITEMNMBR> 
  <SERLNMBR>2-2-2-2</SERLNMBR> 
  <LOCNCODE>RETURN</LOCNCODE> 
  <SLTSQNUM>1</SLTSQNUM> 
  <SVC_Original_Serial>1</SVC_Original_Serial> 
  </taFSRMALineSerial>
  <taFSRMALineSerial xsi:nil="true" /> 
  </taFSRMALineSerial_Items>    
- <taFSRMALine_Items>    
- <taFSRMALine>    
  <Return_Record_Type>1</Return_Record_Type>     
  <RETDOCID>RMA0KFP000002</RETDOCID>     
  <RETTYPE>RP</RETTYPE>     
  <RETSTAT>20</RETSTAT>     
  <CUSTNMBR>BBTFINANC027494</CUSTNMBR>     
  <ADRSCODE>PRIMARY</ADRSCODE>     
  <ITEMNMBR>VX510 DC</ITEMNMBR>     
  <ITEMDESC>0126011 - P/N M251-060-36-NAA VX510 DC 6-meg</ITEMDESC>     
  <LOCNCODE>RETURN</LOCNCODE>     
  <RETORIG>1</RETORIG>     
  <LNITMSEQ>100</LNITMSEQ>     
  <QUANTITY>1</QUANTITY>     
  <UOFM>EACH</UOFM>     
  <CUSTOWN>1</CUSTOWN> 
  </taFSRMALine>
  <taFSRMALine xsi:nil="true" /> 
  </taFSRMALine_Items>    
- <taFSRMAMaster>
  <Return_Record_Type>1</Return_Record_Type> 
  <RETDOCID>RMA0KFP000002</RETDOCID> 
  <RETORIG>1</RETORIG> 
  <RETSTAT>10</RETSTAT>     
  <RETTYPE>RP</RETTYPE>     
  <LOCNCODE>RETURN</LOCNCODE>     
  <CUSTNMBR>BBTFINANC027494</CUSTNMBR>     
  <ADRSCODE>PRIMARY</ADRSCODE>     
  <CUSTNAME>BB&T Financial, FSB</CUSTNAME>     
  <CONTACT>Attn.: BB&T Equipment Manager</CONTACT>     
  <ADDRESS1>2713 Forest Hills Road</ADDRESS1>     
  <CITY>Wilson</CITY>     
  <STATE>NC</STATE>     
  <ZIPCODE>27893</ZIPCODE>     
  <Bill_To_Customer>BBTFINANC027494</Bill_To_Customer> 
  </taFSRMAMaster>
  </FSRMAType>
  </eConnect>
```

Comment: I found the problem. It helps if you use the proper count when creating the object.

 

taFSRMALineSerial_ItemsTaFSRMALineSerial[] serialitems = new taFSRMALineSerial_ItemsTaFSRMALineSerial[LineCount];



taFSRMALine_ItemsTaFSRMALine[] lineitems = new taFSRMALine_ItemsTaFSRMALine[LineCount];